Privileges link icon obfuscates the text
The link icon of the Privileges link in the profile is positioned a little to much to the left. Something like a margin-right: -20px; would fix it, but it should be checked if it breaks something else.



Browser: Firefox 43.0.1 on Win 8.1 x64
Yay! Free-hand circles!

I can confirm this behavior.

Firefox 43 on a Debian OS – same glitch.  // aside: +1 for the “free-hand circle” approach ;)

Big Meta Dupe: The ::after selector for external links is positioned with the text

Can someone confirm it's been fixed?

@Paweł It's fixed for me. :)
